# Updating Vb.net deprecated code

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb this is the code i am working on:

```
Dim InputDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
InputDoc.LoadXml(tem)
Dim Transformer As XslCompiledTransform = New XslCompiledTransform()

Transformer.Load(Server.MapPath("D/" & T))
Dim xmlCtl As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml
xmlCtl.Document = InputDoc
xmlCtl.Transform = Transformer
Controls.Add(xmlCtl)
```

I changed `XslTranform` to `XslCompiledTranform` - is this right thing to do? 
But i am still getting few other errors as xmlCtl.Document is obselete and value of xmlCtl.Transform cannot be converted to Transformer. I am using .Net 4.0 . Can anybody please tell me how to resolve these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I changed XslTranform to XslCompiledTranform - is this right thing to do?

As to [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0610k0w4.aspx) yes that is the right thing to do.
Apparently there is an issue with [memory leakage](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/7fa6bbc4-c115-454f-af8e-0740b09d3b3a) when transforming large documents. So i guess be wary of that.

> But i am still getting few other errors as xmlCtl.Document is obselete and value of xmlCtl.Transform cannot be converted to Transformer

This would be right if you were not going to have XSLT transformations.

```
Dim xmlCtl As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml = New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Xml
```

But you want to use XSLT, so that will not work.

Create an `XPathDocument` and call `CreateNavigator()`
Use [XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx) to execute an XSLT transformation.

[This post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/xmlandnetfx/thread/a5bdb371-5870-4f04-881d-46db7a2f1ce9) talks about working with xml web controls and xslt.

You may want to take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f54faw%28VS.80%29.aspx) as well.

[This uses XslCompiledTransform](http://www.xmllab.net/) and is supposed to be a replacement of the ASP.NET Xml control. Will work with integrating `XSLCompiledTransform`

Anyways i hoped some of this helped.